# react-native-sketch module and component not working at all

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  requireNativeComponent,
} from 'react-native';
import Sketch from 'react-native-sketch';


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  sketch: {
    height: 250, // Height needed; Default: 200px
  },
});

export default class paintChalledgeNative extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.clear = this.clear.bind(this);
    this.onReset = this.onReset.bind(this);
    this.onSave = this.onSave.bind(this);
    this.onUpdate = this.onUpdate.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      drawing: null,
    };
  }


  onReset() {
    console.log('bye bye drawing');
  }


  onSave() {
    this.sketch.saveImage(this.state.drawing)
      .then(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  onUpdate(base64Image) {
    this.setState({ drawing: base64Image });
  }
  clear() {
    this.sketch.clear();
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Sketch
          fillColor="transparent"
          strokeColor="#111111"
          strokeThickness={2}
          imageType="png"
          onReset={this.onReset}
          onUpdate={this.onUpdate}
          ref={(sketch) => { this.sketch = sketch; }}
          style={styles.sketch}
        />
        <Button
          onPress={this.clear}
          title="clear drawing"
        />
        <Button
          disabled={!this.state.encodedSignature}
          onPress={this.onSave}
          title="Save drawing"
        />

      </View>
    );
  }
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('paintChalledgeNative', () => paintChalledgeNative);
```

building sketch app using 'react-native-sketch' the simulator is running but the sketch feature is not woking at all and the clear button crashes the app with and error in the image , the console is logging 20 similar error msgs to the one below
'In file included from /Users/waltershub/Desktop/paintChalledgeNative/node_modules/react-native-sketch/RNSketch/RNSketch.m:11:
../react-native/React/Base/RCTEventDispatcher.h:18:3: error: redefinition of enumerator 'RCTTextEventTypeChange'
  RCTTextEventTypeChange,'

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you've used the `0.5` version of `react-native-sketch`, which wasn't compatible with React Native > 0.40. Since then, a new `1.0` version [has been published](https://github.com/jgrancher/react-native-sketch/commits/v1.0.0), so maybe you could try again with this one?
 (Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of react-native-sketch)